# Login to Facebook by simulating browser HTTP request

Tags: facebook

Good day.

Probably, i have any conceptual mistake in this subject, but i can not understand where is it.

1. I got content from www.facebook.com
2. recieved values of:

   - lds, lgnrnd, lgnjs
   - datr from response cookie
3. formed post request to 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1" with required body (email, pass, etc)+ set cookie from previous
4. I got start page content. Authorisation did not done.

What was left out?

Comment: P.S.
I tryed to login to mobile version: m.facebook.com.

According with recieved content, authorisation was passed, BUT!.. i not recieved   required cookies, like :c_user, fr, lu.....

Need help

Comment: Resolved.

It was required redirection turn off